# Iphone, phone gap, childbrowser and email functionality

Tags: objective-c, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

i have recently built my first app using phone gap and have managed to get childbrowser working to open PDF's. I was wondering if anyone knew how, or if it was even possible to add email functionality to Childbrowser. Currently, in the top right of the ChildBrowser bar, there is a button that produces a drop down with the option to open it in iBooks, SIGNificant and Dropbox, is it possible to edit this to add an email button or just add an email button straight into the UI bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that this cannot be done without using Obj-C. perhaps it will be included in later versions.